# If I restart one instance of REDIS, delete PID and sock files of others

Tags: redis

I have 5 instance of REDIS in Ubuntu 18.04:

- /etc/redis/redis.cfg
- /etc/redis/redis-6380.cfg
- /etc/redis/redis-6381.cfg
- /etc/redis/redis-6382.cfg
- /etc/redis/redis-6383.cfg

I can restart or reload any 6830 to 6383 but if I restart/stop/any redis.services it delete pid and sock file in /var/run/redis of others instances but the instance still running but stuck and they don't work.

/etc/redis/redis.cfg:

```
port 6379
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/redis.log
dir /var/lib/redis
```

/etc/redis/redis-6380.cfg:

```
port 6380
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis-6380.sock
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-6380.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-6380.log
dir /var/lib/redis/redis-6380
```

/etc/redis/redis-6383.cfg:

```
port 6383
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis-6383.sock
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-6383.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-6383.log
dir /var/lib/redis/redis-6383
```

Exist any configuration so that this doesn't happen? the all processes aren't children of redis.services  so I don't understand why it del the others pid and sock files